# Non-example to PBW theorem

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, pbw-theorems

I am interested in a (simple) example of an associative algebra $A$ with 1 generated by $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ which is quadratic (i.e. all relations between $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ have degree $\leqslant 2$) such that elements $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are linearly independent but elements $x_1^{k_1} \ldots x_n^{k_n}, k_1 > \ldots > k_n$ do not form a basis of $A$ (preferably some elements of this form of degree $2$ are linearly dependent).

UPDATE: Thank you for simple examples. In fact what I really want to ask is something like this: Suppose that relations are of the form
$[x_i, x_j]=\sum_{ijk} c_{ijk}x_k$, but without Jacobi identity. What we can say in this case?

Comment: The free algebra is an example!

Comment: quadratic means that "relations are generated by relations of degree 2", not that "all relations have degree $\le 2$".

Comment: If you kill $x_1^2$, then obviously the family is linearly dependent since $x_1^2$ is zero.

Comment: Rather than listing trivial counterexamples, it might make more sense to ask which quadratic algebras satisfy the PBW theorem, since it might be classifiable.

Comment: @YCor Zero hope for classification, it's VERY wild family of algebras. But there are certain characterisations which non-Koszul algebras could satisfy PBW and which Koszul ones do not.

Comment: Ok, that is really not intereseting. But let have really similar to PBW situation: realtions are [x_i, x_j]=\sum_{ijk} c_{ijk}x_k, but without Jacobi identity. What we can say in this case?

Comment: Doesn't Jacobi trivially follow from associativity?

Comment: In case it helps anyone, "PBW theorem" is the [Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Birkhoff%E2%80%93Witt_theorem), giving an explicit description of the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's answer the updated question. Let $A$ be an associative algebra generated by elements $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ with relations of the form
$$ [x_i,x_j] = \sum_{ijk} c_{ijk}x_k.$$
Let $\mathfrak a$ denote the subspace spanned by $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

Theorem: The elements $x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_n^{k_n},~k_1\geq \cdots\geq k_n$ form a basis of $A$ if and only if $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are linearly independent and $\mathfrak a$ is preserved by the commutator bracket.

Proof: The right-to-left implication is the classical PBW theorem for Lie algebras, because $A$ must be the universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{a}$ which has basis $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. The nontrivial part of the left-to-right direction is that existence of PBW basis implies that $\mathfrak a$ is preserved by the commutator bracket. To see this, note that we have a filtration $\mathfrak{a}=A^1\subseteq A^2 \subseteq \cdots$ such that $A^k$ is spanned by elements which can be written as a product of at most $k$ generators. Furthermore there is a quotient map from $A^2/A^1$ to $C^2/C^1$, where $C$ is the symmetric algebra on the vector space $\mathfrak a$. The existence of the PBW basis implies that this quotient map is an isomorphism. Equivalently, that $[a,b] \in \mathfrak{a}$ for all $a,b \in \mathfrak{a}$.

As Simon Wadsley pointed out in the comments, if the coefficients $c_{ijk}$ are chosen in a manner which violates the Jacobi identity, then $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ will already be linearly dependent in $A$. For instance, if we have generators $e,h,f$ and impose the relations
\begin{align}[e,f] &= h\\ [h,e]&=2e \\ [h,f]&=-f\end{align}
then we find that $$0 = [h,h] = [h,[e,f]] = [[h,e],f] + [e,[h,f]] = [2e,f]+[e,-f]=2h-h=h,$$
so $h$ must be equal to $0$ in $A$.